MySQL Permissioning a User to CREATE/LOAD/UPDATE temporary tables?
I have a user that I have already permission to be able to CREATE a temporary table, however when she tries to load a csv file into that temporary table, we're getting a restricted access error for loading. In general, she is not permissioned to load a csv file into any real tables. I only want her to be able to load data into any temporary table she wants. How can I achieve this?

What version of MySQL are you using? Since 5.7, the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE permission allowed performing any operations on the temporary table you create. Before that, you also needed the specific permissions on the database.

I don't think you can restrict access to just temp tables. You can grant a schema-level privilege, but then it'll apply to all tables. You'll have to restrict the user's actions through other means (i.e. code or simply policy), not SQL privileges.

what does select version(); show?

You will likely need to grant insert/load permissions on the table.  You may need to try this:
-- Grant INSERT or LOAD privileges on temporary tables
GRANT INSERT, LOAD ON your_database_name.your_temporary_table TO 'your_user_name'@'your_host_name';


"Table-level privileges apply to base tables and views. They do not apply to tables created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE, even if the table names match." Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Ahh.  Good call, Bill.  It looks like you the insert/load permissions on a temporary table will already be in place for a user in a session where the temp table is created.  So my additional advice to the OP is to ensure that the user is loading the data from the same account in the same session that was used to create the temp table.

The purpose of the temporary tables is so that we can perform an update to a table in bulk with a csv file. (create a temp table that mimics the real table, then join and update real table). I don't know another way of updating a table in bulk. Is there another way?

Since temporary tables only exist in the session that created it, that's an obvious requirement that has nothing to do with permissions.

@LaChelle Use a permanent table rather than a temporary table. As long as you don't have two processes trying to do the bulk update at the same time. Then you can give the user INSERT and DELETE permissions on the table.

Or depending on the types of updates, you might be able to accomplish them directly in a LOAD DATA statement. They would have to be row-by-row changes, i.e. no aggregation.
